# Check if there's an item inside a list and if True modify it

Tags: python

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
def ex(example_list):
     for number in example_list:
         if(number == 2):
              number = 3

ex(list1)
print(list1)
```

I need to check if there is the number 2 inside of the list1 and if it's inside of it, I want to modify it to 3.
But if I run the command, `number` would be `3`, but `list1` would remain `[1,2,3]` and not `[1,3,3]`

Comment: What if there are multiple 2's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()` to get the index of the number you need to change:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
def ex(example_list):
     for idx, number in enumerate(example_list):
         if(number == 2):
              example_list[idx] = 3

ex(list1)
print(list1)
```

The variable `number` is an object with its own reference and not a reference to the item in the list.

Answer (score 3):

The logic for checking and replacing can be done altogether in a *list comprehension* using a *ternary operator* since you're not actually using the index:

```
list2 = [3 if num==2 else num for num in list1]
```

---

References:

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

[Conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

In order to modify a list item, you need to know which slot it is in. The `.index()` method of lists can tell you.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
i = list1.index(2)
list1[i] = 2
```

Now what happens if the list does not contain `2`? `index()` will throw an exception, which normally will terminate your program. You can catch that error, however, and do nothing:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
try:
    i = list1.index(2)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:    # no error occurred
   list1[i] = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

So... The problem you're having is that, since `number` contains a basic type (an `int`), modifying `number` doesn't modify the reference inside the list. Basically, you need to change the item within the list by using the `index` of the item to change:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
def ex(example_list):
     for i, number in enumerate(example_list):
         if(number == 2):
              example_list[i] = 3  # <-- This is the important part

ex(list1)
print(list1)
```

Of just using the index (might be clearer):

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
def ex(example_list):
     for i in range(len(example_list)):
         if(example_list[i] == 2):
              example_list[i] = 3

ex(list1)
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`l.index(n)` will return the index at which `n` can be found in `list` l or throw a ValueError if it's not in there.

This is useful if you want to replace the first instance of `n` with something, as seen below:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> # Don't get to try in case this fails!
>>> l[l.index(2)] = 3 
>>> l
[1, 3, 3, 4]
```

If you need to replace *all* 2's with 3's, just iterate through, adding elements. If the element isn't 2, it's fine. Otherwise, make it 3.

```
l = [e if e != 2 else 3 for e in l]
```

Usage:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l = [e if e != 2 else 3 for e in l]
>>> l
[1, 3, 3, 4]
```